# IntelliJ/PyCharm Debugging with Conditional Breakpoint: Function parameter not defined

Tags: python, debugging, intellij-idea, pycharm, conditional-breakpoint

I am observing the following weird behavior in IntelliJ 2020.03 with Python 3.9 on a Mac (but this also occurrs on another IntelliJ Version on an Ubuntu system).

If we consider the following  minimal example:

```py
def foo(bar):
   pass

foo(False)
```

Now I set a *conditional* breakpoint in IntelliJ in line 2 that conditions on:

```
[bar for _ in range(1)]
```

When I now run the script in debug mode, I get an error:

```
Error while evaluating expression: [bar for _ in range(1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <listcomp>
NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

So my question is simple: Why is `bar` not defined in the generator? (The crucial point to reproduce is to reference `bar` in some generator, otherwise it is defined (of course?)

Answer (score 2):

Regrettably, it has been confirmed as a bug https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47695.

I apologize for the inconvenience.